# Dynamic SQL always output the same data

Tags: c#, sql

I got a serious problem. So my problem is that actually I have 3 *checkbox* in my *form* (C#) :

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

Here's my short sql snippet:

```
AND (

        <isNotEmpty property="Apple">
          M.SUPPLIER = 'a' OR
        </isNotEmpty>
        <isNotEmpty property="Orange">
          M.SUPPLIER = 'b' OR
        </isNotEmpty>
        <isNotEmpty property="Banana">
          (M.SUPPLIER != 'a' and M.SUPPLIER != 'b')
        </isNotEmpty>
)
```

So all I want to do is that I want to view Apple data only if I uncheck the `Orange` and `Banana` *checkbox* or if I check `Orange` *checkbox* it will only show `Orange` data only. BUT the problem with my code is that it always output the same data even if I check all or uncheck them.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Look at the sql being generated by your c# code and you'll probably see why you are getting what you are getting.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks. gonna look into it.